# Relationship between Rademacher distribution and Normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

Is there any relationship between Rademacher distribution and  Normal distribution? The  Rademacher distribution is given as

The probability mass function of this distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution) is

${\displaystyle f(k)=
\left\{{\begin{matrix}1/2&{\mbox{if }}k=-1,\\1/2&{\mbox{if }}k=+1,\\0&{\mbox{otherwise.}}\end{matrix}}\right.}$

In terms of the Dirac delta function, as

${\displaystyle f(k)={\frac {1}{2}}\left(\delta \left(k-1\right)+\delta \left(k+1\right)\right).}  $

Comment: If the mean of the normal distribution is $0$ then both are symmetric wrt $0$. Further I am not aware of any relationship between the distributions. If it is something that can be found then what exactly **is** a relationship between two distributions?

Comment: "How to find the relationship" What on earth does that mean?

Comment: If you found the answer useful you might as well mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the comments on  "relationship between the distributions".  But what I am saying is you can approximate the sum of Rademacher random variables by a Normal distribution.

If random variable X has a [Rademacher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution), then $\frac{X+1}{2} $has a $Bernoulli(1/2)$ distribution.

Sum of i.i.d $Bernoulli(1/2)$ random variables follows a Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p  = 1/2$, where $n$ is the number of trials. So, for sufficiently large $n$ and a given $p $, the Binomial distribution can be approximated by Normal distribution, i.e.  ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {N}}(np,\,np(1-p))}$.

Comment: Thanks. That means we can approximate  a random variable X which has a Normal distribution by  a rv with Rademacher distribution.

Comment: No. One can approximate the sum of iid Rademacher random variables by a Normal distribution. This result comes from [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). And, why would you want to approximate a random variable X which has a Normal distribution by a rv with Rademacher distribution? And, what you are asking for is kind of a converse of CLT. I am not sure about that.